# Why does the code given below gives the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?

Tags: python, string, indices

the code gives error when i try to print the substring

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    n=int(len(string)/max_width)
    i=0 
    j=max_width+1
    for _ in range(n):
        print(string[i,j])
        i=j
        j+=max_width

    print(string[i,len(string)])
```

Comment: The reason you get that error is that string indices must be integers. You're trying to use an incorrect string index type. What do you expect `string[i,j]` to return? Maybe you meant `string[i:j]` instead? `i,j` is of type tuple, so it's not a valid string index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct function

```py
def wrap(string, max_width):
    n=int(len(string)/max_width)
    i=0 
    j=max_width+1
    for _ in range(n):
        print(string[i:j])
        i=j
        j+=max_width

    print(string[i:len(string)])
```

You get error because you can not take chars from a string with `string[i,j]` and `string[i,len(string)]`. In Python ":" is used to take chars from a string.

Comment: Thanks... Silly mistake 

Comment: No problem, everyone can make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
string[i,j]
```

is invalid formatting. You can only put one argument when you're trying to get a particular index of a string, and that argument has to be an integer. So the problem here is that python is interpreting `i,j` as a tuple, not an integer.

You're probably trying to slice the string from index `i` to index `j`. In that case, the syntax is

```
string[i:j]
```

which works because `:` tells python that this is a *slice*, and to look for a separate index on the left and right side of the `:`.